# INSERT INTO SELECT query with foreign key constraint not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I am trying to copy data from production to development database. The production database name is `GRIT` and the development is `GRIT_Prod_Test`.

There are two tables related in this problem one is `Location` and other is `MinorStructures`. `Location.Id` is a foreign key to `MinorStructures.PointId`. I have populated the `Location` table with the data from production to development.
Now I am using `INSERT INTO SELECT` query to populate the table of `MinorStructures`.

This is the code:

```
INSERT INTO GRIT_Prod_Test.dbo.MinorStructures ([PointId]) 
    SELECT [PointId] 
    FROM GRIT.dbo.MinorStructures
```

I get this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_MinorStructures_ToLocationPoint". The conflict occurred in database "GRIT_Prod_Test", table "dbo.LocationPoint", column 'Id'.

So how can I use the `INSERT INTO SELECT` query for foreign key constraint. Or what can be the cause of this problem? Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I dont see a record with Id 10 in production LocationPoint table. However since development database is a new one there exists a record 10 which possibly is the record 11 of the production database. Can it be the problem for not copying MinorStructures records from production to development.

Comment: Stop using comments to add useful(?) information. Edit your post. And yes - it can be a problem. Obviously there is a FK between MinorStructures and LocationPoint. So you need to insert the appropriate rows into LocationPoint first BEFORE you insert the MinorStructures rows.

Comment: Okay. Sorry about that. I will do it from next time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
The problem was as my comment mentions that a record with id 10 in production was not available so the record with id 11 in production became the record with id 10 in development database. So I used `IDENTITY_INSERT` in the `LocationPoint` table in development and inserted the `ID` column values from production to development as well. Then when I copied the records in the `MinorStructure` it worked.